# Class constructor inheritance using `extends` with passed in arguments

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What is the proper way to get the `Child` object to inherit its parents values when they are passed into the constructor vice being hard coded?

In the snippet I am passing in four properties yet the `Child` does not get those values unless I put them directly in. As you see the console log comes up with `null` `NaN` `undefined` if I use arguments when creating an instance of `Parent`.

```js
class Parent {
  constructor(x, y, w, h) {
    this.x = x; //if I put values directly here it works
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.pt1 = {x: this.x, y: this.y};
    this.pt2 = {x: this.x + this.w, y: this.y};
    this.pt3 = {x: this.x + this.w, y: this.y + this.h};
    this.pt4 = {x: this.x, y: this.y + this.h};
  }
}

let parent = new Parent(300, 50, 50, 200);
let child = new Child();
console.log(child.pt1)
console.log(child.pt3)
```

As you see below by not passing them in as arguments the child is now able to inherit the `Parent` values. They objects are linked so let's not say they have no relation.

```js
 class Parent {
      constructor() {
        this.x = 300; 
        this.y = 50;
        this.w = 50;
        this.h = 200;
      }
    }

    class Child extends Parent {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.pt1 = {x: this.x, y: this.y};
        this.pt2 = {x: this.x + this.w, y: this.y};
        this.pt3 = {x: this.x + this.w, y: this.y + this.h};
        this.pt4 = {x: this.x, y: this.y + this.h};
      }
    }

    let parent = new Parent();
    let child = new Child();
    console.log(child.pt1)
    console.log(child.pt3)
```

Comment: `new Child()` has no values for these properties. What do you expect it to inherit from?

Comment: I expect it to inherit the values from `Parent`. Since there's some confusion of inheritance here I'll make another snippet showing how.

Comment: You mean the `child` object should inherit the values of the `parent` object? That's not how class inheritance works.

Comment: Seems to work that way in the snippet I just posted. If its not then where is child getting the x and y values from?

Comment: Take a step back and think about your code. You could easily call `new Parent()` twice, then which one would you expect `new Child` to use the data from? Class inheritance is about inheriting _function_ behavior, not about inheriting data from other instances of the class, so you seem to be fundamentally misunderstanding what class inheritance is for.

Comment: It is getting its *own* values, initialised by the parent constructor (with constants in the second snippet). The `parent = new Parent()` is a separate object, it's not required at all, the `child = new Child()` exists independently of that. The term "*inheritance*" refers to how `Child` extends the set of properties, the *type interface*, that `Parent` has.

Comment: @loganfsmyth this makes sense to me now  "Class inheritance is about inheriting function behavior, not about inheriting data from other instances of the class"

Comment: @bergi ok I'll have to rethink what I was doing now. I thought it was a way to extend all instances of an object

Comment: @Justin What do you mean by "*instances of an object*"?

Comment: I am referring to `let object = new Parent(20, 30, 30, 30)` and for every `Parent` instance that I create, I pass those arguments so I could have a child that inherits them. Now that I think about it, it doesn't make sense since JS wouldn't know which child should receive which `Parents` values. I hadn't thought that far ahead because I was stuck on just trying to get the one to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `parent` and `child` are class objects and they dont have relation each other. From your code, when you call `let child = new Child()`, you did nothing with the `x`, `y`, `w` and `h` in your `Child` constructor.

The Classes are templates, the inheritance means you copy the parent's methods implementation.
You can just think the `Parent` and `Child` classes are different each other - just the `Child` class has all the methods that the `Parent` has.

When you inherit a class, you need to pass the parameters that the `Parent` class needs in its constructor.

You can fix it like below:

```js
class Parent {
  constructor(x, y, w, h) {
    this.x = x; //if I put values directly here it works
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor(x, y, w, h) {
    super(x, y, w, h); // <- Passing the parameters
    this.pt1 = {x: this.x, y: this.y};
    this.pt2 = {x: this.x + this.w, y: this.y};
    this.pt3 = {x: this.x + this.w, y: this.y + this.h};
    this.pt4 = {x: this.x, y: this.y + this.h};
  }
}

let parent = new Parent(300, 50, 50, 200);
let child = new Child(300, 50, 50, 200); // <- pass the values 
console.log(child.pt1)
console.log(child.pt3)
```

Comment: What do you mean they don't have a relation to eachother? that makes zero sense since the Child extends the Parent. If I were to type `this.x = 300;` into `Parent` and then `console.log(child.x)` the value would show because it was inherited from `Parent`. But when I pass it in as an argument it no longer gets read. Passing in `x, y, w, h` into the child does not allow it to inherit those values.

Comment: I meant the instances - `parent` and `child` doesnt have relation. The `Class`es are templates, the inheritance means you copy the parent's methods implementation.

Comment: You can just think the `Parent` and `Child` classes are different each other - just the `Child` class has all the methods that the `Parent` has.

Comment: @Justin The `Child` extends the `Parent` yes but `parent` is not the parent of `child`. Each of them are separate objects that has nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 0):

there has different with `class` and `instance`.you should search some infomation about OOP(Object-oriented programming).
you can regard class as a template.when `new Class` means copy a template to new object(instance).
when `extend`(inherit) means copy a template to a template.and copy all variable from Parent template.
as your code.when Child class extend from Parent.means copy Parent template to Child template.
when you new Parent template.result as copy(create) from Parent Template to an Object(lower parent).
so at this moment `parent Object` has no relation with `Child(upper) Template(Class)`